# Raspberry Pi3 Pyton 3.8 PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, raspberry-pi

Есть RasPi3 и программа, которую я сделал в IDE на винде
На винде поставлен Python 3.8 и PyQt5
Всё работает. 
Установил на RasPi3 PyQt5
Запустил программу. Ругнулось на sys.exit(app.exec())
Посмотрел версию Питона. 2.7
Понял, что справедливо ругнулось. 
Установил на RasPi3 Python 3.8 [как описано здесь](https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/)
Python -V выдаёт Python 3.8.0
Затем установил PyQt5
sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5
Но при запуске программы не может импортировать модули из Qt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
Что я сделал не так / не сделал?
Как сделать, чтобы питон 3.8 увидел Qt?
Если запустить программу как python3 prog.py то всё работает. Питон 3.7, который идёт вместе с Raspbian, Qt видит

Спасибо

Comment: А через `pip` не пробовали ставить?

Comment: я бы порекомендовал таки использовать 3.7

Comment: Через pip ставится для второго питона, через pip3 для 3.7 На питоне 3.7-то всё работает, просто интересно, как для 3.8-то поставить.